# Check If the user have the according field from DocumentSnapshot FirebaseFirestore, Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to check ! If the user has the according `field` or not

like this example is "groupId"

If not I want it to show `Text('no data');`
If has I want it to show a Elevated button.
***But the problem is. That whether it has the data or not it's still show the Elevated Button***.
so how can I fix that?

[image]

here's the code

```
class _HalfScreenState extends State<HalfScreen> {
    final groupId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot?>(
       stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection("users")
        .doc(groupId)
        .snapshots(),
       ///The problem is HERE
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data?.get("groupId") == true) {
        return const Text('no data');
      }
      return Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(
              (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)['groupId'],
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                    child: const GroupScreen()),
                (route) => false),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.grey,
              onPrimary: Colors.black,
              elevation: 0.0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
     }
   }
```

I've been solving it for 4hours now but this is by far I've got.
So if you guys know plz considered helping.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUkzg.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUkzg.png

Comment: I think I gonna need more answers guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          (snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['groupId'] == "" 
          ? Text('no data');
          : ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(
              (snapshot.data!.data() as DocumentSnapshot)['groupId'],
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                PageTransition(
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                    child: const GroupScreen()),
                (route) => false),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.grey,
              onPrimary: Colors.black,
              elevation: 0.0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
```

Comment: It says _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
on the (snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['groupId'] == ""   line

Comment: oh, try: snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['groupId'] == ""

Comment: I mean  I try to add the "!" and "?" Behind the data But It’s still say _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are two things mixed up, you are probably misusing group-id and user-id for the same thing.

You are assigning the user-id as group-id:

`final groupId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`

Then, you search for a user by said group-id:

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(groupId)`

Finally, you are trying to access the groupId-field of the user you found:

`snapshot.data?.get("groupId") == true`

**Try something like this**

```dart
final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`

// ...

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userId)

// ...

(snapshot.data()?.containsKey('groupId')
  && snapshot.data()?['groupId'] != "" 
          ? Text('no data');
          : ElevatedButton( ... )
```

Comment: Can you try to implement it in the full code. Because when I use your code it's says error